# CollectionChanged in ObservableCollection is null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collections, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection of objects of a certain class. When I assign it a new value my CollectionChanged is null and UI don't update. If I in constructor set beginning items to Collection like this:

```
    public TabPageViewModel()
    {
        tabPageDatas = new ObservableCollection<TabPageDataModel>
        {
            new TabPageDataModel(null, "test1"),
        };

    }
```

Then at start my app I see new TabItem, but if I set new value, then no.

```
public class TabPageViewModel : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<TabPageDataModel> TabPageDatas
    {
        get => tabPageDatas;
        set
        {
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TabPageDataModel> tabPageDatas;

    public TabPageViewModel()
    {
        tabPageDatas = new ObservableCollection<TabPageDataModel>();
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}



private void AddNewTabItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    ObservableCollection<TabPageDataModel> newTab = tabPageViewModel.TabPageDatas;
    newTab.Add(new TabPageDataModel(bitmapImage, "Test2");
    tabPageViewModel.TabPageDatas = newTab;
}
```

XAML:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabPageDatas, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabControl.DataContext>
            <ViewModels:TabPageViewModel/>
        </TabControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: You have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead of INotifyCollectionChanged. The latter is already implemented by the ObservableCollection class. Also make sure to set the backing field of the property, i.e. `tabPageDatas = value;` before firing the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: And setting `Mode=TwoWay` on an ItemsSource Binding is pointless. Such a Binding is always implicitly OneWay.

Comment: I add inheritance from interface INotifyPropertyChanged and to set add `tabPageDatas = value;` and invoke event, but this is too null.
I deleted `Mode=TwoWay`.



 `
public ObservableCollection<TabPageDataModel> TabPageDatas
        {
            get => tabPageDatas;
            set
            {
                tabPageDatas = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TabPageDatas)));
            }
        }`

Comment: Also ensure that `tabPageViewModel` is assigned to the view's DataContext. The XAML declaration assigns a different instance to the DataContext.

Comment: I add in MainWindow constructor
` TCTabs.ItemsSource = tabPageViewModel.TabPageDatas;` and now work but I don't understand why it's work.

Comment: You should have set `DataContext = tabPageViewModel;` and remove the DataContext assignment from XAML.